# What did this lecturer mean in this comment on C# tools?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, code-analysis

In the beginning of 2011, I attended a C# seminar where the lecturer said something like the following: "In the future, I expect more tools like ReSharper and CodeRush to emerge because Microsoft has released `#something#`. This means that you no longer need to write your own C# compiler from scratch".

Unfortunately, I didn't catch what `#something#` is. Do you have any suggestions? (I've tried to mail the lecturer, but he didn't reply.)

EDIT: Maybe he said "C# parser", not "C# compiler".

Comment: Does ReSharper/CodeRush really have their own C# compilers? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, I don't know. Of course, I might have misunderstood the lecturer.

Comment: On another thought, he may have been referring to the C# Compiler as a Service work that MS is investigating atm, [Project Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/16/hiring-for-roslyn.aspx)

Comment: The statement does not make full sense to me

Comment: Someone has voted to close this question. A comment on that: Of course, no-one can read the lecturer's mind; however, it should be possible to make an educated guess as to what he was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably referring to [the rumors that C# 5.0 will include a "compiler as a service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197709/c-language-speculation-4-5-5-0) which will make it easy to compile arbitrary C# (and presumably other languages) code through a simple, efficient, method call, with all the supporting AST support that is integral to products such as ReSharper and CodeRush.

Answer (score 1):

Must be compiler as service, already available in Mono - http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler